# Double permutation cipher

Tags: python, encryption

How to implement a double permutation cipher?
Keys are rearranged in alphabetical order (columns and rows do not need to be sorted alphabetically). I wrote a single permutation, how to make a double permutation?

```
def Cipher(origin_key, origin_text):
    clear_text = ''.join(origin_text.split()).lower()
    k = len(clear_text) // len(origin_key)
    cipher = {}

    # Populate the cipher dictionary
    for index, ch in enumerate(origin_key.lower()):
        if ch in cipher:
            cipher[ch] += clear_text[index * k: index * k + k]
        else:
            cipher[ch] = clear_text[index * k: index * k + k]

    # Reconstruct the cipher text
    cipher_text = ''.join([''.join([cipher[key][index] for key in sorted(cipher.keys())]) for index in range(k)])

    # Break the cipher text into chunks of length k and convert to uppercase
    return ' '.join([cipher_text[index: index + k] for index in range(0, len(cipher_text), k)]).upper()
```

The size of the matrix to be filled is selected. The plain text is written along the rows of the matrix, the encrypted text is read along the columns, this is about a permutation cipher without keys. Now for the keys. There is a keyword in the header of the columns, and a keyword in the rows (to the left of the matrix). Next, we rearrange the keys in alphabetical order (only the keys), along with this, the places of columns and rows are changed. Then write down the cipher in the same way

Comment: First you're going to have to tell us what a double permutation cipher is.  Is it just one cipher followed by another?